# Get values from a string based on a format

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I am trying to get some individual values from a string based on a format, now this format can change so ideally, I want to specify this using another string.

For example let's say my input is `1. Line One - Part Two (Optional Third Part)` I would want to specify the format as to match so `%number%. %first% - %second% (%third%)` and then I want these values as variables.

Now the only way I could think of doing this was using RegEx groups and I have very nearly got RegEx works.

```
var input = "1. Line One - Part Two (Optional Third Part)";

var formatString = "%number%. %first% - %second% (%third%)";
    
var expression = new Regex("(?<Number>[^.]+). (?<First>[^-]+) - (?<Second>[^\\(]+) ((?<Third>[^)]+))");
    
var match = expression.Match(input);
    
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Number"].ToString().Trim());
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["First"].ToString().Trim());
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Second"].ToString().Trim());
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Third"].ToString().Trim());
```

This results in the following output, so all good apart from that opening bracket.

> 1 Line One Part Two (Optional Third Part

I'm now a bit lost as to how I could translate my format string into a regular expression, now there are no rules on this format, but it would need to be fairly easy for a user.

Any advice is greatly appreciated, or perhaps there is another way not involving Regex?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to create your own DSL (the format string) to define the parsing rule for the input string? In that case you might want to look into writing your own little parser that handles this (which is a bit more work, but could turn out to safe time in the long run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You included in your pattern couple of special characters (such as `.`) without escaping them, so Regex does not match `.` literlally.

Here's corrected code of yours:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var input = "1. Line One - Part Two (Optional Third Part)";

var pattern = string.Format(
    "(?<Number>{0})\\. (?<First>{1}) - (?<Second>{2}) \\((?<Third>{3})\\)", 
    "[^\\.]+", 
    "[^\\-]+", 
    "[^\\(]+", 
    "[^\\)]+");

var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Number"]);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["First"]);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Second"]);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Third"]);
```

Sample output:
[image]

If you want to keep you syntax, you can leverage `Regex.Escape` method. I also written some code that parses all parameters within `%`

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var input = "1. Line One - Part Two (Optional Third Part)";

var formatString = "%number%. %first% - %second% (%third%)";

formatString = Regex.Escape(formatString);

var parameters = new List<string>();
formatString = Regex.Replace(formatString, "%([^%]+)%", match =>
{
    var paramName = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var groupPattern = "(?<" + paramName + ">{" + parameters.Count + "})";
    parameters.Add(paramName);
    return groupPattern;
});

var pattern = string.Format(
    formatString, 
    "[^\\.]+", 
    "[^\\-]+", 
    "[^\\(]+", 
    "[^\\)]+");

var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

foreach (var paramName in parameters)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[paramName]);
}
```

Further notes

You need to adjust part where you specify pattern for each group, currently it's not generic and does not care about how many paramters there would be.

So finally, taking it all into account and cleaning up the code a little, you can use such solution:

```
public static class FormatBasedCustomRegex
{
    public static string GetPattern(this string formatString,
        string[] subpatterns,
        out string[] parameters)
    {
        formatString = Regex.Escape(formatString);

        formatString = formatString.ReplaceParams(out var @params);

        if(@params.Length != subpatterns.Length)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        parameters = @params;

        return string.Format(
            formatString,
            subpatterns);
    }

    private static string ReplaceParams(
        this string formatString, 
        out string[] parameters)
    {
        var @params = new List<string>();
        var outputPattern = Regex.Replace(formatString, "%([^%]+)%", match =>
        {
            var paramName = match.Groups[1].Value;
            var groupPattern = "(?<" + paramName + ">{" + @params.Count + "})";
            @params.Add(paramName);
            return groupPattern;
        });

        parameters = @params.ToArray();

        return outputPattern;
    }
}
```

and main method would look like:

```
var input = "1. Line One - Part Two (Optional Third Part)";

var pattern = "%number%. %first% - %second% (%third%)".GetPattern(
    new[] 
    {
        "[^\\.]+",
        "[^\\-]+",
        "[^\\(]+",
        "[^\\)]+",
    },
    out var parameters);

var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

foreach (var paramName in parameters)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[paramName]);
}
```

But it's up to you how would you define particular methods and what signatures they should have for you to have the best code :)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the most complete answer. I used this as a starting point and wrote an extension method `ParseString` which returned a `Dictionary<string, string>` containing the token key/value. Really appreciate this.

Comment: This seems to make a huge assumption to me - that the non-field characters will always be `.`,`-`,`(`,`)` in that order.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex:

```bash
^(?<Number>[^.]+)\. (?<First>[^-]+) - (?<Second>[^(]+)(?: \((?<Third>[^)]+)\))?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ojkh1s/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?<Number>[^.]+)`: Match and capture 1+ of any char that is not `.`
- `\.` : Match `". "`
- `(?<First>[^-]+)`:
- `-`: Match `" - "`
- `(?<Second>[^(]+)`: Match and capture 1+ of any char that is not `(`
- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `\(`: Match space followed by `(`
  - `(?<Third>[^)]+)`: Match and capture 1+ of any char that is not `)`
  - `\)`: Match `)`
- `)?`: End optional non-capture group
- `$`: End

Comment: This doesn't address the requirement: "how I could translate my format string into a regular expression".

Answer (score 0):

Your format contains special characters that are becoming part of the regular expression. You can use the `Regex.Escape` method to handle that. After that, you can just use a `Regex.Replace` with a delegate to transform the format into a regular expression:

```
var input = "1. Line One - Part Two (Optional Third Part)";
var fmt = "%number%. %first% - %second% (%third%)";

var templateRE = new Regex(@"%([a-z]+)%", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var pattern = templateRE.Replace(Regex.Escape(fmt), m => $"(?<{m.Groups[1].Value}>.+?)");

var ansRE = new Regex(pattern);
var ans = ansRE.Match(input);
```

Note: You may want to place `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of the `pattern` respectively, to ensure the format must match the entire input string.